# Cannot render Plotly table to html via using CherryPy framework - table is created successfully and saved to temp-plot.html

Tags: python, plotly, cherrypy

I have successfully created a Plotly table using my data in a pandas df format.

However, upon hitting my route, the table is created, but stored in a `temp-plot.html` file, and the page I want it rendered to simply displays the `temp-plot.html` as text, but nothing else.

I know the table is created correctly because, if I open the html file, I see the table with my data.

I'd prefer not to use a templating language (Jinja2) because, unfortunately, this app isn't using it anywhere and I'd prefer not to do a lot of refactoring.

I'd like to simply `render` or `open` my html file, but also send that plot with it.

I've tried sending the data as an argument to `open()` but it says it only supports strings.

I've tried `render()`, but cherryPy doesn't seem to have that method.

```
@cherrypy.expose()
def my_table(self):
    dbtable = db.get_table('v_data')
    with db.session_scope('my_table()') as session:

        query = <get all my data from this table>

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(query)
        trace = go.Table(
            header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                        fill=dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                        align=['left'] * 5),
            cells=dict(values=[my_headers],
                       fill=dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
                       align=['left'] * 5))

    data = [trace]
    sp_table = plot(data)
    return sp_table
```

I expected the table to render to the html page, but I get the title of the html page in text, but no errors. The html page generated by plotly open and shows the table just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `div` output format for the `plot` function... and read more [their docs](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#initialization-for-offline-plotting). But to answer you question, on how to serve the generated html, you can serve the file with `cherrypy.lib.static.serve_file`

```
import os.path
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file

# [...]

@cherrypy.expose()
def my_table(self):
    dbtable = db.get_table('v_data')
    with db.session_scope('my_table()') as session:

        query = <get all my data from this table>

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(query)
        trace = go.Table(
            header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                        fill=dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                        align=['left'] * 5),
            cells=dict(values=[my_headers],
                       fill=dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
                       align=['left'] * 5))

    data = [trace]
    # assuming "plot" returns the filename
    # (otherwise set the `filename` arg in `plot`) and
    # the file is generated in the current directory
    sp_table = os.path.abspath(plot(data))
    return serve_file(sp_table)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had been searching the cherrypy docs but couldn’t find that. Your recommendation makes sense. I have used the div output before, but mistakenly thought cheerypy wouldn’t let me do that.